# Understanding multidimensional indexer

Tags: c#, indexer

I'm well versed in the basic usuage of OO C# but am a little stumped, i'm not sure what the following (simplification from a large project) does exactly and how the parameters are passed:

```
Class test1
{
private prefr iniread;

   private void checkData()
   {
      this.iniread["string1"]["string2"][0][0]
   }
}

public class prefr :
    Component,
    ISupportInitialize,
    ISettingsLoader
{
    #region Events
    public event EventHandler Loading;
    public event EventHandler Loaded;
    public event EventHandler Saving;
    public event EventHandler Saved;
    #endregion

    #region Attributes
    private string _FileName;
    private Dictionary<string, ppPrefSection> _Sections;
    private Control _SaveControl;
    private Control _FinishControl;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public prefr()
    {
        _Sections = new Dictionary<string, prefrSection>();
    }

    public prefr(IContainer container)
        : this()
    {
        container.Add(this);
    }

    public prefr(string Filename)
        : this()
    {
        if (Filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Filename");
        if (!File.Exists(Tools.ReplaceFilenameMacros(Filename))) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Filename '{0}' not found.", Filename), "Filename");

        _FileName = Tools.ReplaceFilenameMacros(Filename);
        if (!Load())
            throw new IOException(String.Format("Error reading '{0}'.", _FileName));
    }

    public prefr(string Filename, bool createNew)
        : this()
    {
        //if (Filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Filename");
        //if (!File.Exists(Tools.ReplaceFilenameMacros(Filename))) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Filename '{0}' not found.", Filename), "Filename");

        _FileName = Tools.ReplaceFilenameMacros(Filename);
        if (!Load(true))
            throw new IOException(String.Format("Error reading '{0}'.", _FileName));
    }
```

It's obvious i'm missing a lot of data here, but from what i've put can anyone clarify how the prefr class utlises the data within the square brackets?

I have missed some data out of the prefr class so may have missed a vital section of the code. How could i go about using the information passed in the square brackets (basic example)?

Thanks

Comment: Well you haven't shown the indexer in `prefr`, which makes it hard to help. Please provide a short but *complete* example. Note that this isn't the normal use of the term "attributes" in C# either.

Comment: Thanks Jon, well the base constructor (no parameters) in prefr contains a list array: _Sections = new Dictionary<string, prefrSection>();. Are we saying the data in brackets is being passed to the target class as an array? Data in brackets formed in such a fashion are always passed as an array? I'm rather confused by this large project which uses the format CLASS[VAR][VAR] as i'm not sure what that particular type of 'call' usually does.

Comment: No, please don't *describe* the code. Edit your question to include a [mcve]. What you're looking for is an indexer: `public SomeType this[string x]` or similar.

Comment: I think that you are talking about Indexers and not about Attributes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: Thanks Elmo, getting there now. So yes, it seems to be a multi dimensional indexer, correct? I'm still a little unclear on how this indexer would be utilised in the class referenced though, could you expand slightly please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is about how this is possible, right?

```
Class test1
{
    private prefr iniread;

   private void checkData()
   {
      this.iniread["string1"]["string2"][0][0]
   }
}
```

i.e. how you can call the `prefr` class using the square brackets?

It's possible thanks to [indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). What might be confusing is that the indexers are used in several steps. i.e. not just `iniread["someName"]` but the `initread["string1"]["string2"][0]`.

But let's start with simple indexers. Here is a trivial example:

```
public class MyRegistry
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _items = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get { return _items[name]; }
    }
}
```

Indexers are just a special property with the name `this` and an argument. So by adding that property you can use

```
var value = theRegistry["someName"];
```

However, you can still not use `theRegistry[0]` as in your example as you would get a compile error. To solve that you just need to add another indexer:

```
public class MyRegistry
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _items = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get { return _items[name]; }
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return _items.Values[index]; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use both `theRegistry["someName"]` and `theRegistry[0]`.

But how on earth did they make it possible to use `theRegistry["someName"]["anotherName"]`?

Well, they return an object which also implement indexer. A trivial example is to build a hierarchy using the same object:

```
public class MyRegistry
{
    Dictionary<string, MyRegistry> _children = new Dictionary<string,MyRegistry>();

    public MyRegistry this[string name]
    {
        get { return _items[name]; }
    }

    //notice that an object is returned instead
    public MyRegistry this[int index]
    {
        get { return _items.Values[index]; }
    }
}
```

Which makes it possible to use `theRegistry["child1"]["child2"][0]`.

Comment: Legendary, you understood me well (despite my fumbled attempt at describing the issue i have), i understand how this application works now :) thanks!

Comment: your welcome. Some people are a bit fast on the down votes instead of trying to read between the lines to see what is really asked. It's not easy to write a well formulated question when you do not know what you are asking for :)